# How can I run a method every page load in MVC3?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, pageload

With WebForms, if I wanted to run a method on every page load, then I would call this method in the `Page_Load()` method of the main Master Page.

Is there an alternative, perhaps better solution, when using MVC3?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the most appropriate way to do this in MVC is with [filters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd410209%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

 MSDN provides a good description of them, and there are dozens of  articles and explanatins about them on the net, such as [this one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg232768.aspx)

**EDIT**
[This](http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/archive/2010/08/15/asp-net-mvc-3-global-action-filters.aspx) sample is even better: It provides a simple action filter, which is then registered in global.asax, and executed on every request, before the actual Action in the relevan controller executes. Such concept allows you to access the request object, and modify whatever you want before the actual controller is executing.

Answer (score 9):

you could create a class base controller

```
 public class BaseController : Controller
{

    public BaseController()
    { 
        // your code here
    }
}
```

and let every new controller of yours impelement the base controller like

```
public class MyController: BaseController
```

also i have found the basecontroller very usefull to store other functions i need a lot in other controllers

Answer (score 1):

You could put the code in the constructor of the controller.
Like this:

```
public class FooController : Controller
{
    public FooController()
    {
        doThings();
    }
```

Comment: Of every controller? I want this to be called on every page load throughout my application

Comment: What if I have 100 controllers? I'm going to have to add this every time. Furthermore I'd have to remember to add this with any new controllers. I don't think this is very scalable.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Sorry, I didn't understand that you wanted this on every view in your application. The basecontroller answer looks good.

Comment: If you have to run different code for each controller, what David suggested makes sense to me and that's what I was looking for. However I agree that it was not what Curt asked for.